# Exporting multiple lines from a foreach loop as arrays not working

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, csv, wmi

I'm working on adapting what was a Multi-Class WMI Query into the same thing but to roll through multiple PC's in a txt file and then append each line from the loop into a CSV

It works fine still with one machine but anytime there is more than one machine name in the list the lines in the CSV appear to not get appended as arrays and each cell reads "System.Object[]"

This is the code I've adapted. I feel like the error is as simple as my formatting of the loop but unfortunately, my knowledge is limited enough that I'm not quite sure how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
#Start


$computers = @(Get-Content -path "C:\users\kyle.ray5\desktop\TestHosts.txt")

$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $computers
$bios = Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS -ComputerName $computers
$physicalMemory = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -ComputerName $computers
$processor = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $computers
$video = Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController -ComputerName $computers
$volume = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -ComputerName $computers
$os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computers
$computerSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computers

foreach($computer in $computers){
    $line = @()
        $o = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ComputerName'      = $computerSystem.Name
        'Manufacturer'      = $bios.Manufacturer
        'Serial Number'     = $bios.SerialNumber
        'Version'           = $bios.Version
        'Operating System'  = $os.Name
        'Service Pack'      = $os.ServicePackMajorVersion
        'CPU Manufacturer'  = $processor.Manufacturer
        'Processor Arch'    = $processor.Architecture
        'Family'            = $processor.Family
        'CPU Name'          = $processor.NumberOfCores
        'Mem Capacity'      = $physicalMemory.Capacity
        'Volume Label'      = $volume.Label
        'Volume Name'       = $volume.Name
        'Total Capacity'    = $volume.Capacity
        'Available Space'   = $volume.Availability
        'Disk Part'         = $disk.Partitions
        'Disk Size'         = $disk.Size
        'Disk Availability' = $disk.Availability
        'Video Card'        = $video.Name
        'GPU Desc.'         = $video.Description
        'GPU'               = $video.VideoProcessor  
    }

    $line += $o

    $line | Export-CSV -Append -Path "C:\users\kyle.ray5\desktop\TestQuery.CSV"
}

#end
```

[This is the output I get when I Put anymore than 1 Hostname in my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTL7C.png)

I tried this with and without adding the `PSCustomObject` to the array `$line` each loop and still receive this result.

Any help would be appreciated as like I said my knowledge is still somewhat limited! Thanks!

Comment: your get-wmiobject commands should be inside foreach

Comment: @Matt Would that work considering not all of the WMI properties I'm collecting are Strings? My understanding is that it would need to be an array as some of the vaules are strings some are booleans etc...

Comment: @VincentK I dont believe that's correct as the Get-WmiObject cmdlts are only gathering the needed information here while the hash-table and the foreach loop are gathering and organizing the properties I want before being appended to the CSV at the end of the loop (supposedly)

If you can provide any info as to why that would be though Im happy to hear it.

Comment: So your CSV file will have computername,version,etc  header and one computername cell will contain all computer names.. because $computersystem.name contains multiple computer names..That is why u r getting System.Object[]

Comment: @VincentK O I see what you mean. So when I'm invoking the methods to collect my properties there are multiple entries since the properties were collected for all systems in the file and its confusing the loop?

I will test that out. Thank you.

Comment: Remove Export-CSV and print $line or $o in the powershell console...See the output...Is that how u want in your CSV file

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
$computers = @("Computer1", "Computer2")


$csvLines = @()

foreach($computer in $computers){

    # IF you don't need any credentials, you can omit the -Credential parameter
    $info = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential (Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {

     
        $disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive 
        $bios = Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS 
        $physicalMemory = Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory 
        $processor = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor 
        $video = Get-WmiObject Win32_VideoController 
        $volume = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume 
        $os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem 
        $computerSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem 

        
        $o = [PSCustomObject]@{
            'ComputerName'      = $computerSystem.Name
            'Manufacturer'      = $bios.Manufacturer
            'Serial Number'     = $bios.SerialNumber
            'Version'           = $bios.Version
            'Operating System'  = $os.Name
            'Service Pack'      = $os.ServicePackMajorVersion
            'CPU Manufacturer'  = $processor.Manufacturer
            'Processor Arch'    = $processor.Architecture
            'Family'            = $processor.Family
            'CPU Name'          = $processor.NumberOfCores
            'Mem Capacity'      = $physicalMemory.Capacity
            'Volume Label'      = $volume.Label
            'Volume Name'       = $volume.Name
            'Total Capacity'    = $volume.Capacity
            'Available Space'   = $volume.Availability
            'Disk Part'         = $disk.Partitions
            'Disk Size'         = $disk.Size
            'Disk Availability' = $disk.Availability
            'Video Card'        = $video.Name
            'GPU Desc.'         = $video.Description
            'GPU'               = $video.VideoProcessor  
        }

        # return content of $o
        $o

    }

    $csvLines += $info

    
}

$csvLines | Export-Csv -LiteralPath C:\temp\test.csv
```

I'm using Powershell remoting ([about remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-5.1)), because it uses a more "standardized" way to get information from remote machines. Remoting is done via `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer`. The content of `-ScriptBlock` is performed on the remote machine. Remoting allows returing values of the `ScriptBlock`, this is simple done by calling `$o` -> since it is the last statement that is not written to any pipeline, the remote Powershell instance returns the content of `$o` over the network.
Be sure that you've enabled PsRemoting on your remote machines -> see [enable PS remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-5.1).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunatly I work for the DoD and PSRemoting / WinRM is blocked here. :/

Answer (score 0):

With Vincents help I was able to get this working. The issue was my formatting of the loop was causing multiple properties to be put in one cell.

Thanks all!